# Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I want to show from UserController how many products the User used and user information. I have created two `Resources` for it. SO I search him using `$id` Here is My `UserController` code

```
public function show($id)
    {
        //
        $user = User::find($id);
        if (is_null($user)) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'User Not Found',
                'status' => 404
            ], 404);
        }
        $products = Product::where('user_id', $user->id)->get();
        return response()->json([
            'data' => new UserProductResource($products),
            'status' => 200
        ], 200);
    }
```

And here is my `UserProductResource`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use App\Http\Resources\ProductResource;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class UserProductResource extends JsonResource
{

    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'first_name' => $this->first_name,
            'last_name' => $this->last_name,
            'profile_img' => $this->profile_img,
            'products' => ProductResource::make($this->products),
            
        ];
    }
}
```

And The error is [image]

My Route is:

```
Route::get('/show-product/{id}', [UserController::class, 'showProduct']);
```

Comment: What's your output code for the `<title>` tag?

Comment: This is an error from Postman.

Comment: find() returns an object so you cant pass directly in where. replace your where condition with where('user_id', $user_id->id) and it will work.

Comment: Thank you but after the changes again it shows me an error.

Comment: Thank You, Dear, It's the help I have just mistake in the relationship functionName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this solution:**

You have a error in this query

```
$products = Product::where('user_id', $user_id)->get();
```

because $user_id is an object of the User, not a single value.

**Your Code:**

```
public function show($id)
{
    //
    $user_id = User::find($id);
    if (is_null($user_id)) {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'User Not Found',
            'status' => 404
        ], 404);
    }
    $products = Product::where('user_id', $user_id)->get();
    return response()->json([
        'data' => new UserProductResource($products),
        'status' => 200
    ], 200);
}
```

**New Code:**

```
public function show($id)
{
    //
    $user = User::find($id);
    if (is_null($user)) {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'User Not Found',
            'status' => 404
        ], 404);
    }
    $products = Product::where('user_id', $user->id)->get();
    return response()->json([
        'data' => new UserProductResource($products),
        'status' => 200
    ], 200);
}
```

Comment: You are right I have changed the code but when I pass to the resource $products it's shown again the same error. But If I send the UserProductResource $user only it shows the user but when I send the $products to UserProductResource it's sending me the same error.

Comment: find() return only 1 result but get() return , so change your UserProductResource  method accordingly.

Comment: User::find($id); returns only 1 user in result but $products = Product::where('user_id', $user->user_id)->get(); returns list of products in result

Answer (score 0):

find($id) returns an object so you cant pass object in where(). Replace your below line

```
$products = Product::where('user_id', $user_id)->get();
```

with this line

```
$products = Product::where('user_id', $user_id->id)->get();
```

it will work.

Comment: You are right I have changed the code but when I pass to the resource $products it's shown again the same error. But If I send the UserProductResource $user only it shows the user but when I send the $products to UserProductResource it's sending me the same error.

Comment: Thank You, Dear, It's the help I have just mistake in the relationship functionName

Answer (score 0):

`new UserProductResource($products)`

Here Object of Products is passed in resource file and if we check fields in UserProductResource they look like fields existing in User model.

Will $products have any field or relation like products ?

$products is a collection so UserProductResource::collection() should be used.

Ideally you should make relationship between User and Product and do this

```
 $user = User::with('products')->find($id);
 if (is_null($user_id)) {
    return response()->json([
       'message' => 'User Not Found',
       'status' => 404
      ], 404);
 }
 return response()->json([
      'data' => new UserProductResource($user),
      'status' => 200
 ], 200);
```

and as there can be multiple products in UserProductResource you can do this

`'products' => ProductResource::collection($this->products),`

Comment: Sorry but I need to find also the products where user $id same Products user_id. Because a user can use multiple products

Comment: Thank You, Dear, It's the help I have just mistake in the relationship functionName